# What is the resulting plane of $plane_1 = plane_2$ intuitively

Tags: intuition, plane-geometry

I have been trying to find the equation of the intersection line between two planes, and was trying some things. The first thing I tried was to just put an equal sign between the two plane equation. I found out the correct way to calculate the intersecting line (). But now I wonder what the resulting plane represents and if it represents anything.

Example:

$8x+6y+3z-30=0$
$10x-2y-4z-10=0$
$8x+6y+3z-30=10x-2y-4z-10$
results in:
$-2x+8y+7z-20=0$
So now I wonder what the relation between this final plane and the two above is.

Comment: Note that the two equations of the two planes are invariant by a scaling factor. Unfortunately, when you equate the two left hand-sides, the result is no more invariant by those scaling factors... The result represents a plane orthogonal to a linear combination of one vector orthogonal to the first plane and one vector orthogonal to the second plane. Which is not very helpful, but still it is orthogonal to the intersection line of the two planes.